# Attempting to cycle through a Pandas df looking for a PU string, from this I wish to record the row number

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
for x in range(lenofdf):
 if df.iloc[0,x][5:7] == 'PU':
     print(df.iloc[0,x])
```

I get the following error

'invalid index to scalar variable.'

I dont understand how it wont work this way but I get a positive result for:

```
if df.iloc[0,2][5:7] == 'PU': print('Bruh')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is highly inefficient to loop through values in a dataframe using a regular Python loop.
 Use the built in DataFrame method of [Iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).
Secondly, it's advised in Pandas to avoid loops altogether, and instead resort to using the dataframe build-in search methods which are much faster.
For example, you can search a specific column for a string using the Series methods:

```
df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('PU')
```

This will output a boolean pandas.Series where each index corresponds to a row in the original column.

Similarly, you can search the entire dataframe using [eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) method as such:

```
df.eq('PU')
```